# Pivot table how to not allow nulls in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, filter, pivot

I want to put a condition if `[2015]` and `[2016]` are NULL then hide row,
but I cant pull it off.

I don't have interest in the `billname` if it doesn't have data.

```
SELECT 
    IssuedByUserGroup,
    BILLNAME, 
    SUM([2016]) AS [2016],
    SUM([2015])AS [2015]
FROM Sum_Orders 
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Sum_SellPrice)
        FOR OrderperiodYear IN ([2016],[2015]) 
) AS pvt
WHERE  ( (MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
    AND day(OrderDate) <= DAY(GETDATE())) OR MONTH(OrderDate) < MONTH(GETDATE())) 
--This part above is just for getting the data since january 1 to sep 23(to the date)
    AND OrderStatus in ('Complete','invoiced') 
    AND OrderPrefix IN ('LAX6') 
GROUP BY BILLNAME,IssuedByUserGroup
ORDER BY IssuedByUserGroup desc
```

This is returning the following as expected:

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) under `GROUP BY` part:

```
HAVING COALESCE(SUM([2016]), SUM([2015])) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks it did work, i would appreciate if you could explain why did it work ?

Comment: COALESCE takes first value, check if it is NULL, if it is not NULL - return this value. If the first value passed is NULL - go to next value and do same check. If all passed values are NULLs - it return NULL. You cannot use SUM (aggregate function) in WHERE part, that is why you need to use HAVING.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a WHERE clause below the PIVOT, something like this:

```
WHERE [2015] IS NOT NULL
```